# Angularjs - How to execute ng-mouseenter once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mousehover

I have a problem, how to execute `ng-mouseenter` or `ng-mousehover` just once

http://plnkr.co/edit/CIdFhCJR8SOatjoDgd8m?p=preview

How to keep that "1" on count?

Comment: This would be better executed as a function.

Comment: how do I break that function?

Comment: Jk, The answer provided is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like this

```
<button ng-mouseover="(count == 0) ? count = count + 1 : return" ng-init="count=0">
```

**IF** `count == 0` then execute the `count = count + 1` **ELSE** just `return`.

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNH3J0T9Lm8YMN3hDIgh?p=preview)

Comment: its glad to help you . :)